# Add Analytics code to Success Checkout Page

Tags: xml, google-analytics

Im adding this to my Local.xml and it just kills my footer.  I want to add my analytics code to the head of just my success checkout page. What am I missing?  Wrong update handle?

```
<checkout_onepage_success>
    <reference name="head">
        <block type="core/text" name="google_tracking" as="google_tracking">
            <action method="setText">
                <text><![CDATA[ <!-- Google Code for Purchases Conversion Page -->
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        /* <![CDATA[ */
                        var google_conversion_id = xxxxxx;
                        var google_conversion_language = "en";
                        var google_conversion_format = "2";
                        var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
                        var google_conversion_label = "xxxxxxx";
                        var google_remarketing_only = false;
                        /* ]]> */
                        </script>
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
                        </script>
                        <noscript>
                        <div style="display:inline;">
                        <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/xxxxxx/?label=xxxxxxxQwonbyAM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
                        </div>
                        </noscript>]]>
                </text>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

Comment: Why not just add it to the success.phtml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing  `/* <![CDATA[ */`. Take a look at [Is there a way to escape a CDATA end token in xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223652/is-there-a-way-to-escape-a-cdata-end-token-in-xml)?

```
<block type="core/text" name="google_tracking" as="google_tracking">
    <action method="setText">
        <text>
            <![CDATA[
            <script type="text/javascript">
                    var google_conversion_id = xxxxxx;
                    var google_conversion_language = "en";
                    var google_conversion_format = "2";
                    var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
                    var google_conversion_label = "xxxxxxx";
                    var google_remarketing_only = false;

                    </script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
                    </script>
                    <noscript>
                    <div style="display:inline;">
                    <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/xxxxxx/?label=xxxxxxxQwonbyAM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
                    </div>
                    </noscript>
            ]]>
        </text>
    </action>
</block>
```

Also take a look at [Magento FacebookRemarketingJs](https://github.com/magepal/FacebookRemarketingJs)